# How to make dynamic scale for bar chart when chart inside a cell. SSRS 2012

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

The goal was to align Chart with Data Table (Excel Style)
This is my chart in design view:

[image]

And this is in Preview mode:

[image]

As you can see series perfectly aligned with each month in a table. 
But is any way to make a scale on a left side in a left cell? And possible dynamic?
Something like that:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just moving the chart outside of the matrix, so it is on it's own? Keeping it in the matrix like that will force it into the one column; it is sourcing it's data from the same column's scope.

Comment: The reason I moved it into a matrix is to perfectly align bars with each corresponding month.

Answer (score 0):

Oleg, here is what I would do.

First, insert another column on the left side of the table. Merge this column with the columns containing total month budget and total month actual.

Next, drag out the left chart and place it below the table. Merge the column where the chart was with the column on the left of that chart. Now drag that table back in and add vertical axis values. You can adjust the size of the column on the left of the chart to get the size right. This won't affect your columns below because they are merged in that row.

You will want to set the size of your vertical axis to be consistent so all of the charts right of the left chart will line up with the values in that axis. Should accomplish what you're looking for!